# Call to `decoded-time-add` produces warning: obsolete timestamp with cdr 1

Tags: time-date

I have the following code:

```
(decoded-time-add
 (make-decoded-time
  :day 1
  :month 1
  :year 2023)
 (make-decoded-time :year 1))
```

When I execute this the following warning gets put out:

> obsolete timestamp with cdr 1 [10 times]

Apparently there is a new time format [since 2018](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-diffs/2018-10/msg00039.html). This change also adds the warning that gets triggered, but I don't understand how this gets triggered through this code.

If I change the code to the following:

```
(decoded-time-add
 (make-decoded-time
  :hour 0
  :day 1
  :month 1
  :year 2023)
 (make-decoded-time :hour 100000))
```

Emacs freezes noticeably before producing the result and prints way more warning:

> obsolete timestamp with cdr 1 [8342 times]

I'm using GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2023-01-19.

From reading the documentation of `decoded-time-add` I think the inputs passed to the function should be valid and the function is not deprecated. Why does the call still produce a warning and why does it freeze my Emacs for certain inputs?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: So is this what your question is: `I don't understand how this gets triggered through this code`. You want to know how it gets triggered? If so, please make that your question explicitly. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug in Emacs 28 which has since been fixed for Emacs 29.

Using `debug-on-message` in Emacs 28.2 I see `(time-add (0 . 1) (0 . 1))` being called and triggering that "obsolete timestamp with cdr 1" error message.  That's getting triggered within `decoded-time-add`, and I can't see anything obviously wrong with your arguments.

In my build of Emacs 29 I see no error and no freezing.